# How to replace the substring after = sign with another value?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text file as below

> set aaadb=test
>
> set aaadbo = dummyvalue1
>
> set aaacdo = dummyvalue2

and so on...

I have the list of key and value pair
like below

> key     Value
>
> aaadb   MyTesting
>
> aaadbo MyTesting1
>
> aaacdo MyTesting3

and so on...

Now I want to output like below

> set aaadb=MyTesting
>
> set aaadbo = MyTesting1
>
> set aaacdo = MyTesting3

Can someone help me how to achieve this using regular expression?

Comment: No regex required, just split on the `=` and replace the corresponding values.

Comment: What do you mean by list of key value? Is it a dictionary of list? Please put code which you tried.

Comment: [Regex](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5eset+%28%3f%3ckey%3e.*%3f%29%3d%28.*%3f%29%24&i=set+aaadb%3dtest&r=set+%24%7bkey%7d%3dcheese)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have list of key value pairs, say Dictionary

```
  var source = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
    {"aaadb", "MyTesting"},
    {"aaadbo", "MyTesting1"},
    {"aaacdo", "MyTesting3"},
  };
```

you can easily ouput them in a required format with a help of *Linq* (no regular expressions here):

```
  string report = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, source
    .Select(pair => $"{pair.Key}={pair.Value}"));

  // Or File.WriteAllText(@"C:\MyFile.txt", report); // if you want to save in the file
  Console.WriteLine(report);
```

Outcome:

```
aaadb=MyTesting
aaadbo=MyTesting1
aaacdo=MyTesting3
```

In you wanna *parse* the file *back* to key/value pairs you can put *regular expressions* there:

```
  var result = File
    .ReadLines(@"c:\MyFile.txt") 
    .Select(line => Regex.Match(
         line, 
       @"^\s*set\s+(?<key>[A-Za-z0-9]+)\s*=\s*(?<value>.*)$"))
    .Where(match => match.Success)
    .Select(match => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(
                            match.Groups["key"].Value, 
                            match.Groups["value"].Value))
    .ToArray(); // Let's get pairs as an array
```

Answer (score 0):

Working sample:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> textFile = new List<string>() { "set aaadb=test", "set aaadbo=dummyvalue1", "set aaacdo=dummyvalue2" };

    Dictionary<string, string> keyValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    keyValues.Add("aaadb", "MyTesting");
    keyValues.Add("aaadbo", "MyTesting1");
    keyValues.Add("aaacdo", "MyTesting3");

    List<string> result = new List<string>();


    foreach (var set in textFile)
    {
        var splits = set.Split('=');
        splits[1] = keyValues.Where(k => k.Key == splits[0].Split(' ')[1]).Select(k => k.Value).FirstOrDefault();

        result.Add(string.Join("=", splits));
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```